# BadPaddingException AES 128 CBC between Python 2 and Java 1.6

Tags: java, python, encoding, aes

I have a Python server script and a Java client application and the goal is to encrypt the data over the socket. The data will always be a string. (I am new to Java)

**What is supposed to happen:**
The Python script creates a socket and listens for connections, accepts new connections, sends the IV in plain-text for AES CBC PKCS5Padding, sets up the ciphers, then receives encrypted data from the Java application (decrypts, then prints out in the terminal), then sends encrypted data to the Java application, then closes the connection.

The Java application connects to the python socket, receives the IV, sets up the same ciphers, encrypts a simple padded string, sends it to the python server, then waits for a reply, decrypts the reply and prints it out to the screen. The connection then closes.

**What is actually happening**
Server sets up socket, java client connects and recieves IV, both setup the same encryption/decryption ciphers, then the java client sends an encrypted padded string. the Python server succesfully receives the ciphertext, decrypts the string and unpads, and the string shows correctly. The server then sends an encrypted padded string to the java client, the client receives the string, then on decryption it fails due a BadPaddingException.

I have verified that the PKCS5 Padding on the python side is correct according to the RFC. I have tried other padding methods (zero-padding, etc), and nothing is working. I have also tried several different encodings on the strings, I have also tried M2Crypto (using pycrypto now), etc. I have tried using CipherInputStream over the socket for the client, and the same result.

Nothing works. I am still thinking there might be an encoding problem between Python and Java, but I am stuck in a rut as to only why the Java client is failing at decrypting.

**Python Server:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, time, threading, json
from socket import *
import sys, base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from socket import *

### Settings
serverHost = '' # localhost
serverPort = 5555 # non-reserved
masterkey = 'mysecretpassword'

BLOCK_SIZE = 16 # Block-size for cipher (16, 24 or 32 for AES)
#PADDING = '{' # block padding for AES

# PKCS5 Padding
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

# generate new IV's - why you ask? ... just look at WEP
def createCipher(key):
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    return (AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv), iv)

class IRCTalkServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, masterkey, host='', port=5555):
        try:
            self.sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # create TCP socket obj
            self.sockobj.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # make port reusable
            self.sockobj.bind((host, port)) # bind socket to port
            self.sockobj.listen(5)                     # listen, allow 5 pending connects
            if host == '': host='localhost'
            print "Started server on %s:%d" % (host, port)
        except:
            print "Error starting server"
            sys.exit(0)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.die = False # loop killer
        self.masterkey = masterkey
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True and not self.die: # infinite loop unless called to quit
                connection, address = self.sockobj.accept()
                print 'Server connected by ', address
                # generate cipher and get first IV - prevent same WEP hacks
                #paddedKey = keypad(masterkey)
                #print "master key:", masterkey, " - padded key:", paddedKey, " - diff key:", keypad('test')
                self.cipher, self.iv = createCipher(masterkey)
                print "IV:", self.iv.encode('hex'), "Sending IV: ", repr(self.iv)
                connection.send("%s%s" % (self.iv.encode('hex'),'\n')) # send iv first
                while True and not self.die: # read from client
                    print "waiting for client"
                    data = connection.recv(10485760)
                    print "recieved from client:", repr(data.rstrip())
                    if not data:
                                                print "NO DATA"
                                                break
                    dataCheck, JSON = self.decryptData(data.rstrip())
                    print 'Recieved from Client:', repr(JSON)
                    #print 'Recieved from Client:', repr(data)
                    #if dataCheck:
                        #senddata = self.encryptData('SUCCESS')
                        #print "Size of compresseddata:", len(senddata)
                        #connection.send(senddata)
                        #morestuff = 'abc123def456'*int(10000/9)
                        #senddata = self.encryptData(['test', morestuff, 'test1', {'key': 'value'}, 2223])
                        #print "Size of compresseddata:", len(senddata)
                        #connection.send(senddata)
                    print "Sending reply to client..."
                    senddata = self.encryptData('test')
                    print "reply data:", repr("%s%s" % (senddata, "\n"))
                    connection.send("%s%s" % (senddata, "\n"))
                    #connection.send("Hello back mr android!")
                    #successReply = connection.recv(256) # only for "END REQUEST"
                                        break
                                print "Closing connection... \n\n"
                connection.close()
        except:
                        print "exception on try loop"
            pass # an error occurred, just drop it, the client will try again later

    def encryptData(self, plaintext):
        # convert to json string, pad the string, then encrypt, then compress
        #JSON = json.dumps(plaintext, separators=(',',':'))
        JSON = plaintext
        #print "Size of JSON:", len(JSON)
        ciphertext = pad(unicode(JSON))
        print "padded text:", repr(ciphertext)
        ciphertext = self.cipher.encrypt(ciphertext)
        print "ciphertext:", repr(ciphertext), "|", len(ciphertext), "|", ciphertext
        ciphertext = ciphertext.encode('hex').upper()
        print "hexified text:", repr(ciphertext)
        #ciphertext = self.cipher.encrypt(pad(JSON)).encode('hex').upper()
        print "Size of ciphertext:", len(ciphertext)
        return ciphertext

    def decryptData(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            # decompress data to ciphertext, decrypt, convert to json
            print "length of ciphertext:", len(ciphertext)
            ptext = ciphertext.decode('hex')
            print "unhexifed:", repr(ptext)
            ptext = self.cipher.decrypt(ptext)
            print "decrypted:", repr(ptext)
            ptext = unpad(ptext)
            print "unpadded:", repr(ptext)
            #ptext = unpad(self.cipher.decrypt(ciphertext.decode('hex')))
            print "ptext: ", repr(ptext)
            JSON = ptext
            #plaintext = unpad(self.cipher.decrypt(ciphertext))
            ##JSON = json.loads(plaintext)
            #JSON = plaintext
        except:
            print "Error on decryption"
            JSON = None
        return (True, JSON)

    def addToQueue(self, data):
        pass

    def getFromQueue(self):
        pass

testserver =IRCTalkServer(masterkey)
testserver.start()
testserver.join()
```

**Java Client:** (parts of this code still needs to be properly credited - [i just haven't done it yet])

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
//import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
//import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

class clientHandler {
    /*
     *  This class sets up AES CBC encryption for the socket, 
     *  new instance for every connection since the IV changes
     */

    // Declare variables
    private Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;
    Socket testSocket = null;
    //DataOutputStream out = null;
    //DataInputStream in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String masterkey = "mysecretpassword";
    static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static String byteToHex( byte [] raw ) {
        if ( raw == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
        for ( final byte b : raw ) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
                .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] hexToByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length();
        byte[] ba = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            ba[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return ba;
    }

    public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        // encrypt string
        try {
            byte[] cipherbyte = ecipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
            //String ciphertext = new String(ecipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF8")));
            return byteToHex(cipherbyte);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String ciphertext) {
        // decrypt hex string
        try {
            System.out.println("decrypt byte length: " + hexToByte(ciphertext).length);
            String tp = new String(hexToByte(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("toString(): " + tp);
            String plaintext = new String(dcipher.doFinal(hexToByte(ciphertext.trim())), "UTF-8");
            //String plaintext = new String(dcipher.doFinal(ciphertext.getBytes("UTF8")), "UTF-8");
            return plaintext;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setupCrypto(byte[] iv, String key) {
        // setup AES CBC encryption
        //  convert IV and key to byte array for crypto
        try {
             System.out.println("Setting up Crypto...");
             //byte[] ivb = iv.getBytes("UTF8");
             byte[] keyb = key.getBytes("UTF8");
             AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
             SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");
             ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
             dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
             ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, paramSpec);
             dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, paramSpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error:" + e);
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        // starts server
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to Server");
            testSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
            //out = new DataOutputStream(testSocket.getOutputStream());
            //in = new DataInputStream(testSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(testSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(testSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Uknown Host");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection");
        }
    }

     public void androidClientHandler() {
         // actual communication
         if (testSocket != null && out != null && in != null) {
             try {
                 System.out.println("Waiting for IV..");
                 String iv;
                 iv = in.readLine();
                 byte [] ivb = hexToByte(iv);
                 System.out.println("Got IV..." + iv);
                 setupCrypto(ivb, masterkey);
                 String ciphertext;
                 String plaintext;
                 System.out.println("Sending \"test\" to server");
                 //out.writeBytes("test\n");
                 ciphertext = encrypt("test");
                 System.out.println("Sent: " + ciphertext);
                 out.println(ciphertext);
                 System.out.println("Waiting for Server to reply");
                 String responseLine;
                 responseLine = in.readLine().replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
                 System.out.println("Recieved from Server: " + responseLine + " - length: " + responseLine.length());
                 plaintext = decrypt(responseLine);
                 System.out.println("Recieved from Server: " + plaintext);
                 System.out.println("Closing Connection");
                 out.close();
                 in.close();
                 testSocket.close();
             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host:" + e);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
             }
         }
     }

     public void javaIsGay() {
         startServer();
         androidClientHandler();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
         clientHandler c = new clientHandler();
         c.javaIsGay();
     }
}
```

**Output of Python Server:**

```
Started server on localhost:5555
Server connected by  ('127.0.0.1', 59683)
IV: c54aae0a5c43f547f0355ee7a0ee38c1 Sending IV:  '\xc5J\xae\n\\C\xf5G\xf05^\xe7\xa0\xee8\xc1'
waiting for client
recieved from client: 'BBE7E09093625204CD3F7B755066419D'
length of ciphertext: 32
unhexifed: '\xbb\xe7\xe0\x90\x93bR\x04\xcd?{uPfA\x9d'
decrypted: 'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
unpadded: 'test'
ptext:  'test'
Recieved from Client: 'test'
Sending reply to client...
padded text: u'test\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
ciphertext: '\x9fT\xfc\xf0\xa8\xc2\xd3N*\x8f\x8e~\xc7\x8a\xbfR' | 16 | �T�����N*~Ǌ�R
hexified text: '9F54FCF0A8C2D34E2A8F8E7EC78ABF52'
Size of ciphertext: 32
reply data: '9F54FCF0A8C2D34E2A8F8E7EC78ABF52\n'
Closing connection...
```

**Output of Java Client:**

```
Connecting to Server
Waiting for IV..
Got IV...c54aae0a5c43f547f0355ee7a0ee38c1
Setting up Crypto...
Sending "test" to server
Sent: BBE7E09093625204CD3F7B755066419D
Waiting for Server to reply
Recieved from Server: 9F54FCF0A8C2D34E2A8F8E7EC78ABF52 - length: 32
decrypt byte length: 16
toString(): �T����N*��~Ǌ�R
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:317)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1813)
    at clientHandler.decrypt(SocketClient.java:70)
    at clientHandler.androidClientHandler(SocketClient.java:134)
    at clientHandler.javaIsGay(SocketClient.java:151)
    at clientHandler.main(SocketClient.java:157)
Recieved from Server: null
Closing Connection
```

Comment: Note that you will also get a `BadPaddingException` if decryption fails because of a wrong key.

Comment: Have you noticed that the sent and received data are not the same: `python - �T�����N*~Ǌ�R`  and  `java - �T����N*��~Ǌ�R`

Comment: yes, which is why I think its an encoding problem, but, base64 encoding or unicode don't seem to solve the problem

Comment: @MByD was correct, i'm losing something along the way. Now why?

Comment: @platinummonkey why do you do trim() when you decrypt the string in java?

Comment: @platinummonkey there seems to be little wrong with Executifs answer, have you tried implementing it?

Comment: Actually it's not correct. The padding routine does pad the extra 16 `\x10`. I should've made a comment about that a long time ago. `len(pad('')) == 16 # True` and `len(pad('a')) == 16 # True`

Comment: @platinumonkey: this is my problem too, do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned trying nopadding, did you try switching the cipher mode? CTR should be just as secure as CBC for your application and doesn't require padding.

Comment: Haven't tried CTR, I'm not sure what a secure method would be for generating a counter to utilize this cipher mode. A java example would be nice if you could provide an example or links.

Comment: Just change AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding to AES/CTR/NoPadding. The only thing with CTR is make sure you don't re-use your IVs and you're safe. Use SecureRandom to generate them every time and you're fine

Answer (score 2):

I may be too late, but here's what I got:
There is a problem in your python padding routine. If the cleartext's size is a multiple of 16, no padding will be added, while Java expects 16 '\x10'.

This may of course not solve your corruption problem during transport. Your best bet would be to check whether the problem comes from the cipher or the transport: how about writing the encoded text in a file and have Java read from it, just to be sure?

Comment: Should've commented about this a long time ago but see comment above. Padding routine does pad the extra 16 `\x10`

Answer (score 0):

In the Java program you are using 2 `Cipher` instances for encryption and decryption both initialize with the same IV; in the python code you are using the same object for both decryption and encryption. I am not familiar with the *pycrypto* library (and not fluent in python neither) but it is more than likely that the encryption object contains an internal state, especially in CBC mode. And if you don't reset the cipher after the initial decryption I'm not sure that you are encrypting the reply with the expected IV, which could explain the exception.

Comment: checked, this didn't solve the problem, although I think MByD was on better target after looking at the data lengths. I seem to be losing a bit somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exception being thrown, when I was using extended security features of Java JDK (particularly - AES encryption and decryption). The key to making this work, was to install extended security policy files for my production JDK. You might try doing this as well.

You can download them here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (search for Java Cryptography Extension at the bottom of the page). After downloading, you'll have to copy both *.jar files into JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security and overwrite previous files.

Hope this helps, regards.

Comment: I gave this a try and unfortunately this didn't solve the problem

Comment: Sorry for bad hint. Hope someone else visiting this site will be able to make use of it ;)

Comment: The extended security features will only unlock AES-192 and AES-256. They won't have any impact on AES-128.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem with you, I am not sure whether the code following will give you an idea.

---

## python code

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
BS = AES.block_size
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

class MyAESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
        """
        Requires hex encoded param as a key
        """
        self.key = key

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        """
        Returns hex encoded encrypted value!
        """
        raw = pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB, self.key)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))
```

//java code

```
private static final String INSTANCE = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
public static String decrypt(String sSrc, String sKey) throws Exception {
        try {
            // 判断Key是否正确  
            if (sKey == null) {
          //      LOGGER.error("Key should not be null");
                return null;
            }  
            if (sKey.length() != 16) {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] raw = sKey.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(INSTANCE);
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(sKey.getBytes());
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] encrypted1 = Base64.decodeBase64(sSrc.getBytes());
            try {
                byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted1);
                return new String(original,"UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          //  LOGGER.error("decrypt fail", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: idea of what? your similar problem?